# How to cite files on a CD-ROM?

Tags: citations, bibtex

I would like to cite one of the descriptions present on the DIEHARD test battery, which is located on a CD-ROM [here](http://stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/cdrom/dos/tests.txt). Specifically, I would like to cite the craps test. If I could have the citation in the form of a BibTeX entry, I would be very glad. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I find the easiest way to cite scientific software is to search it on Google Scholar and see if anyone else has cited it. In this case, searching for "DIEHARD: a battery of tests of randomness" yields one result that's been cited in 614 papers. Clicking the cite button and picking BibTex gives the following:

```
@article{marsaglia1997diehard,   
  title={The Diehard random number testsuite},
  author={Marsaglia, George},
  journal={http://stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard},
  year={1997}
}
```

You may want to throw a \url{} around the address, but otherwise that should work for you. Just mention the specific test in your paper when you cite it.